# Are there any known issues upgrading from jQuery 1.4.1?

Tags: jquery

Does anyone have experience upgrading from jQuery 1.4.1 to 1.4.3 or 1.4.4. I'm wondering if there are known gotchas.

Thanks
v.

Comment: 1.5 is just about to get released btw.

Answer (score 1):

I know few http://api.jquery.com/val/

---

I had problems with this one recently. To make it work i use $('select options:selected').val() instead of $('select').val() which used to work before 1.4.4.

jQuery 1.4.4 breaks .val() when trying to set the selected option of a select.
It works ok in jQuery 1.4.3 and earlier versions.

---

for the jQuery 1.4.4, .val( true ) for the checkbox type input sets it attribute value=true, not checked=true, leaving checkbox unchecked

If you look in Internet I am sure you will be abl to find more info.